# How to get the below result

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'CA')
   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'MX')


   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'CA')
   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'GB')

   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'CA')
   INSERT INTO @PaymentsTable1 VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'IN')

   DECLARE @Count INT

   SELECT @Count = COUNT(DISTINCT PMJ.CountryCode) FROM  @PaymentsTable1 PMJ GROUP BY PMJ.PId

   IF (@Count >= 3)
          SELECT DISTINCT Pkey, PId, DataId FROM @PaymentsTable1 
   ELSE
          SELECT 0 AS [Pkey], 0 AS [PId], 0 AS [DataId]
```

I need records which are having different country code >=3

In  this scenario, only the 2nd record should return. With this implementation,

what is the logic to come both PId records to come.

Comment: Different PKey records to come

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include table definition, I assumed that you have columns in following order: `PKey, PId, DataId, CountryCode`. So in case code doesn't work, you'll need switch order of columns :)

This should solve your problem :)

```
;with cte as (
select PKey, PId, DataId from @PaymentsTable1
group by PKey, PId, DataId
having Count(distinct CountryCode) >= 3
)
select * from cte
union all
select 0 as PKey, 0 as PId, 0 as DataId where not exists(select * from cte)
```